# Problems with jQuery function "carouFredSel()" in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, caroufredsel

I'm starting in development, more precisely in .net, and I speak a bit of english. I'll do the best I can.

I have a problem with jQuery function carouFredSel(), specifically with the width of a responsive carousel when the window is maximized: in Firefox it works perfectly, but in Chrome and IE (in other explorers I have not tried it yet) the width of the carousel at the right of the screen is exceeded.

The HTML is:

```
<div id="cuerpo-img">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div>
            <img src="[image path]" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="[image path]" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="[image path]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

The Javascript code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        items: {
            visible: 1
        },
        scroll: {
            duration: 400,
            timeoutDuration: 4500,
            fx: 'uncover-fade'
        },
        pagination: '#pager'
    });
});
```

And the CSS code is:

```
#carousel div 
{
    height:275px;
    float: left;
    z-index:0;
}
#carousel img 
{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Try to change "min" with "max" in CSS file

Comment: @bicho it's doesn't works, because the image is quite small and if I change 'min' with 'max' the image is never going to enlarge.

Comment: It will help you http://beta.matizmo.net/plugin/examples/responsive-carousels.php.html